# Parse JSON Array Data to Jade Template from Nodejs server

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to loop through and display my JSON object array data on my jade template. 
I'm thinking it may be my JSON object but I'm not sure. 
I've tried to stringify and not on the Render command.

I've tried each command with jade and every other answer given on here for anything close to what i'm looking for. I think my disconnect is with how JADE works.

```
dailyforecastdata = {
    days: []
  };


for (var key in forecastdata) {    //look through data at the period level 
  nameoutput = forecastdata[key].name
  numberoutput = forecastdata[key].number
  starttimeoutput = forecastdata[key].startTime
  endtimeoutput = forecastdata[key].endTime
  isdaytimeoutput = forecastdata[key].isDaytime
  temperatureoutput = forecastdata[key].temperature
  temperatureunitoutput = forecastdata[key].temperatureUnit
  temperatureTrend = forecastdata[key].temperatureTrend
  windSpeed = forecastdata[key].windSpeed
  windDirection = forecastdata[key].windDirection
  icon = forecastdata[key].icon
  shortForecast = forecastdata[key].shortForecast
  detailedForecast =  forecastdata[key].detailedForecast

dailyforecastdata.days.push({
'name' : nameoutput,
'number' : numberoutput,
'starttime' : starttimeoutput,
'endtime' : endtimeoutput,
'isday' : isdaytimeoutput,
'temp' : temperatureoutput, 
'tempunit': temperatureunitoutput,
'temptrend' : temperatureTrend, 
'windSpeed' : windSpeed, 
'windDirection' : windDirection, 
'icon' : icon, 
'shortForecast' : shortForecast, 
'detailedForecast' : detailedForecast
});


 res.render("nws", {forecastdata: JSON.stringify(dailyforecastdata)});
 //res.render("nws", {forecastdata: dailyforecastdata});



.JADE FILE
I knowp #{forecastdata} isn't what i need but it's the only thing i've gotten to work in any way of displaying my data. 

extends layout

block content
    h1 Weather Forecast
    p #{forecastdata}
```

OUTPUT OF #{forecastdata}

```
{"days":[{"name":"Today","number":1,"starttime":"2019-05-15T11:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-15T18:00:00-05:00","isday":true,"temp":86,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"10 mph","windDirection":"SE","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/tsra_hi,20/sct?size=medium","shortForecast":"Slight Chance Showers And Thunderstorms then Mostly Sunny","detailedForecast":"A slight chance of showers and thunderstorms before noon. Mostly sunny, with a high near 86. Southeast wind around 10 mph, with gusts as high as 20 mph. Chance of precipitation is 20%."},{"name":"Tonight","number":2,"starttime":"2019-05-15T18:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-16T06:00:00-05:00","isday":false,"temp":64,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"10 mph","windDirection":"S","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/few?size=medium","shortForecast":"Mostly Clear","detailedForecast":"Mostly clear, with a low around 64. South wind around 10 mph."},{"name":"Thursday","number":3,"starttime":"2019-05-16T06:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-16T18:00:00-05:00","isday":true,"temp":92,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"10 to 20 mph","windDirection":"SW","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/few?size=medium","shortForecast":"Sunny","detailedForecast":"Sunny, with a high near 92. Southwest wind 10 to 20 mph, with gusts as high as 35 mph."},{"name":"Thursday Night","number":4,"starttime":"2019-05-16T18:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-17T06:00:00-05:00","isday":false,"temp":68,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"15 mph","windDirection":"S","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/few?size=medium","shortForecast":"Mostly Clear","detailedForecast":"Mostly clear, with a low around 68. South wind around 15 mph, with gusts as high as 30 mph."},{"name":"Friday","number":5,"starttime":"2019-05-17T06:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-17T18:00:00-05:00","isday":true,"temp":86,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"15 to 20 mph","windDirection":"S","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/sct?size=medium","shortForecast":"Mostly Sunny","detailedForecast":"Mostly sunny, with a high near 86. South wind 15 to 20 mph, with gusts as high as 35 mph."},{"name":"Friday Night","number":6,"starttime":"2019-05-17T18:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-18T06:00:00-05:00","isday":false,"temp":68,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"15 to 20 mph","windDirection":"S","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/bkn/tsra_sct,20?size=medium","shortForecast":"Mostly Cloudy then Slight Chance Showers And Thunderstorms","detailedForecast":"A slight chance of showers and thunderstorms after 1am. Mostly cloudy, with a low around 68. Chance of precipitation is 20%."},{"name":"Saturday","number":7,"starttime":"2019-05-18T06:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-18T18:00:00-05:00","isday":true,"temp":78,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"15 mph","windDirection":"S","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/tsra,20/tsra,80?size=medium","shortForecast":"Slight Chance Showers And Thunderstorms","detailedForecast":"A slight chance of showers and thunderstorms before 1pm, then showers and thunderstorms. Mostly cloudy, with a high near 78. Chance of precipitation is 80%."},{"name":"Saturday Night","number":8,"starttime":"2019-05-18T18:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-19T06:00:00-05:00","isday":false,"temp":55,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"5 to 10 mph","windDirection":"S","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/tsra,80/tsra,60?size=medium","shortForecast":"Showers And Thunderstorms","detailedForecast":"Showers and thunderstorms. Mostly cloudy, with a low around 55. Chance of precipitation is 80%."},{"name":"Sunday","number":9,"starttime":"2019-05-19T06:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-19T18:00:00-05:00","isday":true,"temp":68,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"10 to 15 mph","windDirection":"W","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/tsra_sct,60/tsra_sct,30?size=medium","shortForecast":"Showers And Thunderstorms Likely","detailedForecast":"Showers and thunderstorms likely before 1pm, then a slight chance of showers and thunderstorms. Partly sunny, with a high near 68. Chance of precipitation is 60%."},{"name":"Sunday Night","number":10,"starttime":"2019-05-19T18:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-20T06:00:00-05:00","isday":false,"temp":48,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"5 to 15 mph","windDirection":"NW","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/tsra_hi,20/sct?size=medium","shortForecast":"Slight Chance Showers And Thunderstorms then Partly Cloudy","detailedForecast":"A slight chance of showers and thunderstorms before 7pm. Partly cloudy, with a low around 48. Chance of precipitation is 20%."},{"name":"Monday","number":11,"starttime":"2019-05-20T06:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-20T18:00:00-05:00","isday":true,"temp":70,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"10 mph","windDirection":"E","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/tsra_hi,20?size=medium","shortForecast":"Slight Chance Showers And Thunderstorms","detailedForecast":"A slight chance of showers and thunderstorms after 7am. Partly sunny, with a high near 70. Chance of precipitation is 20%."},{"name":"Monday Night","number":12,"starttime":"2019-05-20T18:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-21T06:00:00-05:00","isday":false,"temp":55,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"10 mph","windDirection":"E","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/tsra,50?size=medium","shortForecast":"Slight Chance Showers And Thunderstorms then Chance Showers And Thunderstorms","detailedForecast":"A slight chance of showers and thunderstorms before 7pm, then a chance of showers and thunderstorms. Mostly cloudy, with a low around 55. Chance of precipitation is 50%."},{"name":"Tuesday","number":13,"starttime":"2019-05-21T06:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-21T18:00:00-05:00","isday":true,"temp":72,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"10 to 15 mph","windDirection":"SE","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/tsra,60?size=medium","shortForecast":"Chance Showers And Thunderstorms then Showers And Thunderstorms Likely","detailedForecast":"A chance of showers and thunderstorms before 7am, then showers and thunderstorms likely. Mostly cloudy, with a high near 72. Chance of precipitation is 60%."},{"name":"Tuesday Night","number":14,"starttime":"2019-05-21T18:00:00-05:00","endtime":"2019-05-22T06:00:00-05:00","isday":false,"temp":55,"tempunit":"F","temptrend":null,"windSpeed":"10 to 15 mph","windDirection":"S","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/tsra_sct,60/tsra_sct,40?size=medium","shortForecast":"Showers And Thunderstorms Likely then Chance Showers And Thunderstorms","detailedForecast":"Showers and thunderstorms likely before 7pm, then a chance of showers and thunderstorms between 7pm and 1am. Mostly cloudy, with a low around 55. Chance of precipitation is 60%."}]}
```

Comment: Have you tried using an `each` loop? https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html

Comment: I sure have, couldn't get it to work. I'm trying to  find an example that uses it with a data set from the server and not in the jade file. I'm thinking maybe it requires some special syntax for it. I just get nothing returned when i've tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If `#{forecastdata}` is correctly outputting your JSON, the following [`each`](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) syntax should work:

```
each day in forecastdata.days
    article
        h2 #{day.name}
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code, I just tried with the data stringified or not and I get nothing new on my page. Sidenote, If i use the non stringify push it returns [object Object] for the #{forecastdata} variable but does show the data in string format when applied

Comment: What happens when you do `p #{forecastdata.days.length}` without stringifying the JSON?